# What is an "auto commit glide input"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is a function in Gboard called "auto commit glide input" - Auto commit the current composing text before the next glide input. Could someone please tell me what "auto commit" means in this context?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To "commit" to something is to decisively choose it:

> I have committed to buying a new car next spring.

When you are typing on a phone with glide input, you draw a pattern in the letters, the phone guesses which words you might mean and gives you a choice. You then choose the correct word. The phone gives you choices, and you manually commit to one of them.

With "auto-commit" the phone will automatically commit to the most likely word if you then enter a new word, so usually you won't have to manually commit to each word you enter.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!!!